# How to get value of the Flow only once and immediately?

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I have created my `DataStore` and I have a boolean value in it:

```
private val DID_REBOOT = booleanPreferencesKey("did_reboot")
val didRebootFlow: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
    .map { preferences ->
        preferences[DID_REBOOT] ?: false
    }
suspend fun setDidReboot(didReboot: Boolean) {
    context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[DID_REBOOT] = didReboot
    }
}
```

Now, on my `BroadcastReceiver` I need to check this value. Depending on the the value, I need to perform database operations:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    if(ds.didRebootFlow.first()) {
        Log.d("-----------------", "true")
    } else
        Log.d("-----------------", "false")
}
```

In some place in my app, I am setting `didRebootFlow` to `true`. But my broadcast is printing `false` (in the second attempt it works fine).

```
2021-04-27 12:42:24.347 7469-7469/com.test.datastore D/-----------------: false
```

I am new to suspended functions and `Flow` and cannot figure it out how to make my code work.

My code logic is strongly dependant on the value of this field. How to get `didRebootFlow` once (and immediately) here?

I do not want to use `.collect { }` because I do not want "observe" `didRebootFlow` continuously. I would like to get its value only **once**. (Because observing `didRebootFlow` non-stop means I will be doing lots of database operations).